# babel-loader not working, giving error on UglifyJS (ES6)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yarnpkg, flipclock

I have implemented the [FlipClockJs vue component](https://github.com/mvpleung/vue-flipclock) and it works fine when I run

> yarn encore dev

However, as soon as I run

> yarn encore production

I get the following error

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors12:30:24 PM
>
> error
>
> app.bc30a410.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: operator (>)
>   [app.bc30a410.js:12470,21]

I tried resolving this by adding this to my webpack file:

```
  .addLoader({
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    include: ['node_modules/@mvpleung/flipclock']
  })
```

But this just gives me the same result. My entire webpack file looks like this:

```js
var Encore = require("@symfony/webpack-encore");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

Encore.setOutputPath("public/build/")
  .setPublicPath("/build")

  .addEntry("app", "./resources/assets/js/app.js")

  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

  .addLoader({
test: /\.vue$/,
loader: "vue-loader"
  })
  .addLoader({
test: /\.js$/,
loader: 'babel-loader',
include: ['/node_modules/@mvpleung/flipclock']
  })
  .addLoader({
test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
enforce: "pre",
loader: "eslint-loader",
exclude: /node_modules/,
options: {
  fix: true
}
  })
  .addPlugin(new VueLoaderPlugin())
  .addPlugin(new MinifyPlugin())
  .addAliases({
vue: "vue/dist/vue.js"
  })

  .enableSassLoader()
  .enablePostCssLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Any idea what might be wrong here? The component works fine when running yarn encore dev.

Using Vue 2.5.17

Comment: [Edited] Why are you including index.js in webpack, and not as an `import` as the documentation recommends? + Vue version?

Comment: Left overs from trial and error. Removed again. In my code I am actually using import { FlipClock } from "@mvpleung/flipclock";

Comment: It looks like Encore's removed UglifyJs since it doesn't support ES6+. Since your error is being thrown by UglifyJs, perhaps you're using an outdated version of Encore? Relevant link: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/b5750b2fb09053687bcaca59b27a79a8396d304b/index.js#L1176

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be the way Encore doc recommends to run a node_module through babel:
```
Encore.configureBabel(null, {
     include_node_modules: ['@mvpleung/flipclock']
});
```

https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/b5750b2fb09053687bcaca59b27a79a8396d304b/index.js#L740

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following in your config

```
  optimization: { minimize: false },
```